# using System.Path when Widget.Path conflicts in GTK/C#

Tags: c#, path, cross-platform, monodevelop

I'm working on a cross platform app using the GTK toolkit and when I'm trying to access the `System.IO` namespace to extract `Path` fields, I'm getting the following error:

> Error CS0119: 'Widget.Path(out uint, out string, out string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context (CS0119) (netmonmd)

I have `using System.IO;` in the source file and I'm using other namespaces without any issue (eg `System.Console` and `System.Refelection` without any issues further down in the code).

I have almost identical code in a console application working without an issue.

Here is the code, if I fully provide the `Path` it works, I just can't use it within the namespace (but I can use other things that are in the same namespace)

```
using Gtk;
using System;
using System.IO;

using static System.Console;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
    private netmonmd.iplabel[] ids;
    private int fSize = 12;

    public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {

        Build();
        //char filesep = System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;  // works
        char filesep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;              // error
```

I'm trying to understand the error (I am new to C#) and think it has to do with calling it within the `MainWindow` function since it seems to be referring to `Widget.Path` and not `System.Path`

Is this a case of just having to fully qualify it each time?

I could move all the code out of the main window and process it elsewhere in the `app.cs` file, however it is a single window app that I was developing in the one space. If it is better practise to separate it out I will do that.

(as is usually the case in asking on stack, while writing this question out I'm becoming more aware of what's actually happening here, I just don't know how to work around it)

Comment: `using Path = System.Path;`

Comment: Ok, I worked on this for a while, I couldn't get `using Path = System.Path` to work, I assume you meant `System.IO.Path`, but it's still trying to utilise `Widget.Path`. I have even changed the order of my `using`s at the top of the file to no avail. What has worked (and I didn't know you could do this) was rename the namespace. By making it a lowercase `using path = System.IO.Path` it magically works. I feel I'm missing something but this will at least keep me going for now.